# addon domains keeps adding primary domain in URL

Tags: linux, htaccess, dns, cpanel, whm

I took new vps plan from inmotionhosting.com and moved my host from previous hosting company. I have several cpanel accounts in the whm, imported them all using the migration tool from server to server.

After many attempts, only primary domain from each account works ok, any addon domain in any cpanel account adds the of the primary add in the URL when visited from the browser, which is very strange, I suspect the dns zone but nobody could help even from the company support.

Example:
    Cpanel account: 'primary'
    Primary domain: primary.com
    Addon domain in same account 'primary' = addon.com

Whenever add new folder or file in new.com: suppose be:
     http://addon.com/folder

Opening it in browser, directly goes to: 
    http://addon.com.primary.com/folder

Opening it in browser for files, says:
    http://addon.com.primary.com/folder/text.txt

But don't work, for sure it shows can't reach to host...

If remove the additional primary link and press enter sometimes it works...

I tried removing all cache and tried from different pc which never used on these sites, all similar... also checked if any htaccess exist, but none...

Anybody has any clue?

Answer (score 1):

your best deal is to contact inmotion hosting support team if its a managed VPS , if its not then check the settings in Domains tab under Tweak settings in WHM.

Comment: I did ask them, they said is from an application which has header redirect and i have to find a developer to fix it!! they don't know anything, just nothing, they can't differentiate between header redirect, htaccess 301 redirect and URL addition in the addon adomain, it is obvious I told them on the chat that I suspect the dns, but they don't want to listen, do you think it was wrong move to take a vps from them?!

Comment: by the way, any other addon domain does the same thing, it is not from an application, they just don't know anything... so i'm going to keep this and see what the guys will say about it..